# DC - migrate FRS to DFSR any issues for 2003 server members?

Tags: active-directory, file-replication-services

Is there any issue to migration DC's from FRS to DFSR if there are still very old "computers" members in the domain ?
the client has a remaining 2003 R2 server and I would like to make sure this won't have any consequence for that device.
I couldn't find anything relevant on google. Does anyone has some experience of migrating DC's from FRS to DFSR with 2003 server members (not DCs - members only)
thanks
D

Comment: Member servers aren't affected by migrating SYSVOL from FRS to DFSR. They don't take part in SYSVOL replication.

Comment: @joeqwerty thanks a lot for confirmation :)